# How to use MPI with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

As a beginner of MPI, I want to use mpi with several threads and each thread communicates using mpi. I tried several approaches but get some errors. First, I tried a very basic implementation like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mpi.h>

// Thread function
void threadFunction(int threadId) {
    int cube = threadId * threadId * threadId;

    // Broadcast the cube using MPI
    MPI_Bcast(&cube, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    std::cout << "Thread " << threadId << " is executing. Cube: " << cube << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // Create 4 threads
    std::thread thread1(threadFunction, 1);
    std::thread thread2(threadFunction, 2);
    std::thread thread3(threadFunction, 3);
    std::thread thread4(threadFunction, 4);

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    thread4.join();

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

My aim use to use further mpi but even this implementation gives the following error

```
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 84 is executing. Cube: 1

Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 1
[lisa:1831051] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831051] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831051] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831051] Failing at address: 0x560bdb8f8360
[lisa:1831171] *** Process received signal ***
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 8
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 8
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 8
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 8
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 64Thread
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 8
1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 4 is executing. Cube: 6427Thread

2 is executing. Cube: 8
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 64
2Thread  is executing. Cube: 31 is executing. Cube: 8

Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 27
[lisa:1831059] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831059] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831059] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831059] Failing at address: 0x558ded578460
[lisa:1831073] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831095] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831095] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831095] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831095] Failing at address: 0x56315bd543e0
[lisa:1831093] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831119] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831119] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831119] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831119] Failing at address: 0x558ded578460
[lisa:1831119] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f811692b520]
[lisa:1831119] [ 1] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(mca_btl_vader_poll_handle_frag+0x154)[0x7f8114024ba4]
[lisa:1831119] [ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(+0x7db1)[0x7f8114024db1]
[lisa:1831119] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.40(opal_progress+0x34)[0x7f811685d714]
[lisa:1831119] [ 4] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_request_default_wait+0x55)[0x7f8116dad0e5]
[lisa:1831119] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_generic+0x5ea)[0x7f8116e0140a]
[lisa:1831119] [ 6] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_binomial+0xbd)[0x7f8116e01f2d]
[lisa:1831119] [ 7] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed+0x40)[0x7f810f5c2640]
[lisa:1831119] [ 8] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(MPI_Bcast+0x121)[0x7f8116dc1881]
[lisa:1831119] [ 9] a.out(+0x9738)[0x563673064738]
[lisa:1831119] [10] a.out(+0xf25e)[0x56367306a25e]
[lisa:1831119] [11] a.out(+0xf1d3)[0x56367306a1d3]
[lisa:1831119] [12] a.out(+0xf133)[0x56367306a133]
[lisa:1831119] [13] a.out(+0xf0e8)[0x56367306a0e8]
[lisa:1831119] [14] a.out(+0xf0c8)[0x56367306a0c8]
[lisa:1831119] [15] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xdc253)[0x7f8116c0d253]
[lisa:1831119] [16] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94ac3)[0x7f811697dac3]
[lisa:1831119] [17] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a40)[0x7f8116a0fa40]
[lisa:1831119] *** End of error message ***
[lisa:1831146] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831146] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831146] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831146] Failing at address: 0xfffffffe
[lisa:1831146] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f26e8c74520]
[lisa:1831146] [ 1] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(+0x7d9a)[0x7f26e1f6bd9a]
[lisa:1831146] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.40(opal_progress+0x34)[0x7f26e8ba6714]
[lisa:1831146] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_request_default_wait+0x55)[0x7f26e90f60e5]
[lisa:1831146] [ 4] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_generic+0x5ea)[0x7f26e914a40a]
[lisa:1831146] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_binomial+0xbd)[0x7f26e914af2d]
[lisa:1831146] [ 6] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed+0x40)[0x7f26e190a640]
[lisa:1831146] [ 7] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(MPI_Bcast+0x121)[0x7f26e910a881]
[lisa:1831146] [ 8] a.out(+0x9738)[0x558dabc7d738]
[lisa:1831146] [ 9] a.out(+0xf25e)[0x558dabc8325e]
[lisa:1831146] [10] a.out(+0xf1d3)[0x558dabc831d3]
[lisa:1831146] [11] a.out(+0xf133)[0x558dabc83133]
[lisa:1831146] [12] a.out(+0xf0e8)[0x558dabc830e8]
[lisa:1831146] [13] a.out(+0xf0c8)[0x558dabc830c8]
[lisa:1831146] [14] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xdc253)[0x7f26e8f56253]
[lisa:1831146] [15] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94ac3)[0x7f26e8cc6ac3]
[lisa:1831146] [16] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a40)[0x7f26e8d58a40]
[lisa:1831146] *** End of error message ***
[lisa:1831145] *** Process received signal ***
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 8
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 27
[warn] event_base_loop: reentrant invocation.  Only one event_base_loop can run on each event_base at once.
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 1
[lisa:1831118] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831076] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831076] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831076] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831076] Failing at address: 0x7f1a4c0049e0
Thread Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 81
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 64
 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 27
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 64
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 27
[lisa:1831154] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831154] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831154] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831154] Failing at address: 0x565235d3b3e0
[lisa:1831154] [ 0] Thread 3 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 27
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7fb50de0f520]
[lisa:1831154] [ 1] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(mca_btl_vader_poll_handle_frag+0x154)[0x7fb50c107ba4]
[lisa:1831154] [ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(+0x7db1)[0x7fb50c107db1]
[lisa:1831154] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.40(opal_progress+0x34)[0x7fb50dd41714]
[lisa:1831154] [ 4] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_request_default_wait+0x55)[0x7fb50e2910e5]
[lisa:1831154] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_generic+0x5ea)[0x7fb50e2e540a]
[lisa:1831154] [ 6] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_binomial+0xbd)[0x7fb50e2e5f2d]
[lisa:1831154] [ 7] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed+0x40)[0x7fb506aa5640]
[lisa:1831154] [ 8] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(MPI_Bcast+0x121)[0x7fb50e2a5881]
[lisa:1831154] [ 9] a.out(+0x9738)[0x55875e9c2738]
[lisa:1831154] [10] a.out(+0xf25e)[0x55875e9c825e]
[lisa:1831154] [11] a.out(+0xf1d3)[0x55875e9c81d3]
[lisa:1831154] [12] a.out(+0xf133)[0x55875e9c8133]
[lisa:1831154] [13] a.out(+0xf0e8)[0x55875e9c80e8]
[lisa:1831154] [14] a.out(+0xf0c8)[0x55875e9c80c8]
[lisa:1831154] [15] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xdc253)[0x7fb50e0f1253]
[lisa:1831154] [16] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94ac3)[0x7fb50de61ac3]
[lisa:1831154] [17] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a40)[0x7fb50def3a40]
[lisa:1831154] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 4 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 1 is executing. Cube: 1
Thread 2 is executing. Cube: 64
[lisa:1831061] *** Process received signal ***
[lisa:1831061] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[lisa:1831061] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[lisa:1831061] Failing at address: 0x10
[lisa:1831061] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f7de4aa6520]
[lisa:1831061] [ 1] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(mca_btl_vader_alloc+0x167)[0x7f7de1d9ae37]
[lisa:1831061] [ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(mca_btl_vader_sendi+0x48a)[0x7f7de1d9e98a]
[lisa:1831061] [ 3] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_pml_ob1.so(+0x14589)[0x7f7de17d3589]
[lisa:1831061] [ 4] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_isend+0x39c)[0x7f7de17d118c]
[lisa:1831061] [ 5] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_generic+0x6d6)[0x7f7de4f7c4f6]
[lisa:1831061] [ 6] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_bcast_intra_binomial+0xbd)[0x7f7de4f7cf2d]
[lisa:1831061] [ 7] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_dec_fixed+0x40)[0x7f7de173e640]
[lisa:1831061] [ 8] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(MPI_Bcast+0x121)[0x7f7de4f3c881]
[lisa:1831061] [ 9] a.out(+0x9738)[0x565234aaf738]
[lisa:1831061] [10] a.out(+0xf25e)[0x565234ab525e]
[lisa:1831061] [11] a.out(+0xf1d3)[0x565234ab51d3]
[lisa:1831061] [12] a.out(+0xf133)[0x565234ab5133]
[lisa:1831061] [13] a.out(+0xf0e8)[0x565234ab50e8]
[lisa:1831061] [14] a.out(+0xf0c8)[0x565234ab50c8]
[lisa:1831061] [15] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xdc253)[0x7f7de4d88253]
[lisa:1831061] [16] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94ac3)[0x7f7de4af8ac3]
[lisa:1831061] [17] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x126a40)[0x7f7de4b8aa40]
[lisa:1831061] *** End of error message ***
[lisa:1831090] *** Process received signal ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 41 with PID 0 on node lisa exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

I compile with mpic++ and run with mpirun, and probably do some fatal mistakes. Can you explain and give examples of how to use mpi with threads and how threads communicate with each other using mpi?

Comment: First you need to `MPI_Init_thread(MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, ...)` since you want all threads to perform communications at the same time. When using MPI collective, an important restriction is that two threads cannot issue the same collective operations at the same time and on the same communicator.

Comment: Broadcast sends one "message" to each process. So if that process has 4 threads, only one of them will receive the broadcast data. What you want is not simply possible.